# Using "->" to navigate structs with pointers

Tags: c, macos, gcc, textedit

I am trying to create a phone book, which is a binary search tree which has a linked list on the end of each leaf, but, I have encountered a "Segmentation fault (Core dumped)" error. I have a feeling it is caused by my "makenode" function which creates the first node of the tree. My structs are the following

```
typedef struct number{
    char number [20];
    struct number *next; 
} Number;

typedef struct list {
    Number *first, *last;
} List;

typedef struct tree {
    char name[20];
    struct tree * left;
    struct tree * right;
    List * next;
} Tree;
```

And my makenode function is

```
Tree *makenode (char name[20], Tree *l, Tree *r, Number e) {
    Tree *newnode;
    newnode = malloc( sizeof(Tree));
    strncpy(newnode->name,name,19);
    newnode->next=malloc(sizeof(List));
    newnode->next->first=malloc(sizeof(Number));
    strncpy(newnode->next->first->number,e.number,11);
    newnode->left = l;
    newnode->right = r; 
return newnode;
}
```

I was just hoping for advice on whether the line

```
strncpy(newnode->next->number,e.number,11);
```

is the line causing the problem, and maybe some advice on why it is causing the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you do not use a debugger? If you do so you will stop at the line which throws the exception. So please use the tools you already have!

Comment: Apology's for beginnerishness, but, how do I use a debugger? And is it built in to GCC?

Comment: yep, because of lack of memory to `newnode->next`

Comment: @ElisJones , Look into GDB

Comment: Your strncpy is weird, you copy sizeof(name) - 1. You should copy everything and ensure the string is terminated by 0 which might not be the case in this code. Adding new node->name[19] = '\0' would do it

Comment: `number` does not exist in member of the `List`

Comment: it doesn't even compile, `newnode->next` has no member named `number`, only `first` and `last`.

Comment: compile with `-g` as flag and use `gdb <progname>`. The gdb manual can be found in the net. Maybe you like to use ddd as frontend for gdb. But starting with simple gdb out of the box will fulfill your needs for first time programming.

Comment: I'm running on a mac at the moment, it's saying gdb:command not found. Is there another solution, or should I wait until I get home, and run it on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segmentation fault because memory is not being allocated to structure `LIST`

```
    newmode->next = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
```